# Move cells, that meet a criteria, to the top of a list

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a retention tracker in Excel.

There will be 8 columns (month, last name, first name, part time vs full time, hire date, termination date, termination reason, and termination detail) in my table.

I want to pull up all employees who have NOT left the previous month, and add them to the top of the list with their information.

```vb
Sub New_month()

Worksheets("Agents").Activate

Dim month As Variant
Dim prev_month As Variant

month = InputBox("Please Enter Month as Abbreviation(i.e, Jan, Feb, etc.)")
rowEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
previous_month = Cells(2, 1).Value

For i = 1 To rowEnd
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = previous_month And Cells(i, 6).Value = "" Then
        new_row_month = prev_month
        last_name = Cells(i, 2).Value
        first_name = Cells(i, 3).Value
        emp_status = Cells(i, 4).Value
        hire_date = Cells(i, 5).Value
        
        Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
        
        Cells(2, 1).Value = month
        Cells(2, 2).Value = last_name
        Cells(2, 3).Value = first_name
        Cells(2, 4).Value = emp_status
        Cells(2, 5).Value = hire_date
            
            
        '' Formatting
        Range("A2:H2").Font.Size = 11
        Range("A2:H2").Font.Color = vbBlack
        Range("A2:H2").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        Range("A2:H2").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Rows("2:2").RowHeight = 15
        Range("A2:H2").Font.Bold = False
        
    End If
Next i
        
End Sub
```

The result after code run once:
[image]

The result after code run twice:
[image]

Comment: If your data is in a Table/ListObject then you're better off using the built-in sorting. If your data isn't in a Table/ListObject, then you're better off using Cut and Insert. With Cut and Insert, your formatting is preserved and the other data is shifted automatically. And there is no chance of duplicating your data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you insert a new row the data gets pushed down the sheet and then you loop through looking at the same row over and over. e.g you look at row 2 to start with, insert a new row, the data moves to row 3 and you look at it again etc.

If you add a counter for each new row then it should work

```
 counter = 0
 For i = 1 To rowEnd
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = previous_month And Cells(i, 6).Value = "" Then
        counter = counter +1
        new_row_month = prev_month
        last_name = Cells(i+counter, 2).Value
        first_name = Cells(i+counter, 3).Value
        emp_status = Cells(i+counter, 4).Value
        hire_date = Cells(i+counter, 5).Value
```